# mapael defaultArea tooltip current Area Name

Tags: tooltip, mapael

how can i set up tooltip on defaultArea, with the name of the area.
I would like to show the name of the current country for the area where the mouse is over.

```
            , defaultArea : {
            attrs : {
                fill: grey
                , stroke: "#BDBDBD"
            },
            tooltip : {
                content : ??????
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue in a similar situation I have in the following way:

`tooltip: {
    // Show Country name on hover
    content : ""+countryObject[this]+""
}`

This references an external Country Name object I've created and included before referencing it, the object looks like this:

`var countryObject = {
    US:"United States",
    AF:"Afghanistan",
    AL:"Albania",
    DZ:"Algeria",
    AS:"American Samoa",
    AD:"Andorra",
    AO:"Angola",
    AI:"Anguilla",
    AQ:"Antarctica",
    AR:"Argentina"
}`